# Architecture for having both a mobile and regular site?

Tags: html, css, mobile, web

I've been asked to develop a mobile version of an existing site and I'm curious about the best way to set everything up.

Does it make more sense to create two separate versions of the site: one for mobile one regular?  If I do this are there any common techniques for synchronizing the content on both sites?

Or should I just create a second version of the CSS that targets `handheld` media types?

Comment: Why don't you use CSS media query fot detecting the mobile device? Then you'll just have to modify the css for the mobile version.

Comment: Isn't that the second solution I proposed?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry. It's late in my country. Anyway, I would suggest that you'll do that. I've done it myself and it's a lot easier.

Comment: I think it really depends on what kind of content you have. What all is on your site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your website is simple text base or blog then it will effective to use "responsive design"

**Responsive web design (often abbreviated to RWD) is an approach to web design in which a site is crafted to provide an optimal viewing experience—easy reading and navigation with a minimum of resizing, panning, and scrolling—across a wide range of devices (from desktop computer monitors to mobile phones)**

Reference

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design